# Looking for a short story on a man imprisoned in his own head

Tags: story-identification

I read a story years back on [365Tomorrows](http://365tomorrows.com/) about a man trapped in a basement by some sort of mad scientist.  He was essentially trapped in his own head for an extreme amount of time.  The time was compressed so that he experienced it at a rate far faster than it actually passed - e.g. 10 seconds was like 10 years.

I've been unable to find it, if anyone knows where I can, that would be awesome!

Comment: http://365tomorrows.com/09/19/ticket-to-paradise/ a similar theme

Comment: I found the answer using http://sitecomber.com/ to do a search of all of the stories on the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [The White Room](http://365tomorrows.com/08/04/the-white-room/) by W. Kevin Christian.

> *The room was not cold. It was not wet. It was not noisy or colorful. It was quiet and white. No pictures on the walls. No carpet on the
>   floors. There was just a table with a man on it and a black-and-white
>   digital clock hung from the ceiling directly above his head. The clock
>   read: 9,999 years, 364 days, 23 hours, 58 minutes, 11 seconds…12…13…*

...

> *A perverse grin crossed the bald man’s face, his mouth letting out a
>   slow, toad-like chuckle. The feeling of power intoxicated him. The
>   look 30 seconds with the program could put on a person’s face! It
>   tickled him in the darkest of ways, as if holding something young and
>   innocent at the edge of a cliff overlooking hell. The power! The
>   suffering!*

Comment: you got it! :) haha

Comment: For the record, this is basically a ripoff of "The Jaunt".

Comment: yeah, I found The Jaunt when I was looking for this story :)

Comment: "9,999 years, 364 days, 23 hours, 58 minutes, 11 seconds"... Hm... It wasn't a leap year, was it?

Comment: @MrLister - There's a 1:4(ish) chance that it was.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be "[The Long Sleep](http://365tomorrows.com/06/07/the-long-sleep/)" by Richard “Zig” Zagorski?

The key premise is that the protagonist is trapped inside his own head during a 200 year voyage.

> For whatever reason, Gerald was not asleep and unaware in stasis – not
>   completely anyway. The only sense that functioned was his hearing. He
>   felt nothing against his skin, he saw nothing …he wasn’t even sure if
>   his eyes were open. And with his nasal passages filled with stasis
>   fluid, he smelled nothing at all. But he could hear the slushing of
>   the stasis fluid being refreshed periodically, as it would do each
>   passing hour of the 200-year voyage.

Comment: Close, but this one was actually some sort of torture device, intentionally made